# Netbeans with Java 9 not creating /dis/lib

Tags: java, netbeans, java-9

I have a project that is developed in netbeans using java 8. Now, I migrated to Java 9 and I am using a development version of netbeans. When I build the project using java 8 platform everything is OK and /dist/lib directory is created with the jars along with the project main jar file, but when I use java 9 platform only the project main jar is created and /dist/lib is not created. 
The build is successful and I can run the project in the IDE the problem is that when I run the project jar it's missing the library jars which are supposed to be in /dist/lib.

Comment: have you added the jars as a dependency on your app?

Comment: During migration, was your project migrated into another build/dependency system, EG Maven?

Comment: is there any APIs that are not accessible during execution ?

Comment: what i would do is remove the jar folders from the dependencies, Do a Clean and Build. Close netbeans and re-add the jar files as Libraries.... Clean and build usually creates the dist folder

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie No they are accessable.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy yes and the classpath is configured

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto no I am nont using maven

Comment: the most strange is that the jars are generated in /ib/dist using java 8 and not generated when using java 9

Comment: How do you manage your dependencies ? are you using modular jigsaw

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie no just referring to them using the classpath, it's a java 8 project

Comment: I can't post the whole build log for the both platforms (java 8 and 9) but the only difference between them is that line: 

Copy libraries to D:\projects\Project1\dist\lib.

when using java 9 it's not copying the libraries

Comment: okay so here is a suggestion that might work, try to use maven instead of referring to libs . your problem is probably caused because the JAR file is not configured probably as a library in your J9 project. if that didn't work we can find a way to configure compile-time libraries using modular jigsaw

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Thanks very much

Comment: Just reported similar issue for NetBeans 9.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1097

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bug in NetBeans. Reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1097

Meanwhile, you can fix it by editing nbproject\build-impl.xml by hand. Find this part:

```
<condition property="do.mkdist">
<and>
    <isset property="do.archive"/>
    <isset property="libs.CopyLibs.classpath"/>
    <not>
        <istrue value="${mkdist.disabled}"/>
    </not>
    <not>
        <istrue value="${modules.supported.internal}"/>
    </not>
</and>
</condition>
```

and delete this part:

```
    <not>
        <istrue value="${modules.supported.internal}"/>
    </not>
```

so that this remains:

```
<condition property="do.mkdist">
<and>
    <isset property="do.archive"/>
    <isset property="libs.CopyLibs.classpath"/>
    <not>
        <istrue value="${mkdist.disabled}"/>
    </not>
</and>
</condition>
```

Then it works as expected - until NetBeans recreates build-impl.xml...

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me.   The issue I encountered were different to that of the OP.  I had projects created in NB 8.2 w/JDK8, and after migration to NB9.0 w/JDK10, the projects built fine, i.e., dist/lib was created.  However, new projects created using NB 9.0 w/JDK10 did not have dist/lib created during built.  The above solution solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Using NB 10.  dist/lib does not get built on new projects.  Above fix works, but I first have to create dist/lib.

Comment: Which above fix works? Is it Ahmad's suggestion? Your answer will be more helpful if you can explain how to solve the problem so that a person with a question similar to the OP will be able to follow.

Comment: Sorry, @joonas Pulakka's fix worked, but first I had to create dist/lib.  This is with netbeans 10.